# Rails 4, Assigning Roles with Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rolify

I'm trying to figure out how to assign roles using Rolify.

I have models for User, Role and Organisation. The associations are:

User

```
rolify strict: true # strict means you get true only on a role that you manually add
attr_accessor :current_role
has_one :organisation, foreign_key: :owner_id
```

Role

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: "users_roles"
belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
```

Organisation

```
resourcify
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
```

I made a new controller called assign_roles_controller.rb. It has:

```
class AssignRolesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @roles = Role.all #rewrite to exclude the global roles which are for admin only
    @users = User.all
    # @users = Organisation.find(@current_user.organisation).user.profiles

    @organisation = Organisation.first
    # @organisation = Organisation.find(@current_user.organisation)
  end


  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @role = Role(role_params)
    @organisation = Organisation.first
    @user.add_role, @role, @current_user.organisation
  end
```

My objective is for the user that is the owner of an organisation - any roles that user assigns to other users, will be scoped to the first user's organisation.

I'm not trying to figure out how to find the relevant users or organisations yet- I've hard wired them to pick all users and the first organisation just to see if I can make the create action work.

I have made an index view for assign_roles/index:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
    <%= select_tag "users", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "formal_name"), { multiple: true , class: "chosen-select form-control" } %>
    </div>

<!-- # roles -->

<!-- u.add_role role, current_user.org -->
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    <%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", "<%= text_for_role(name)%>"), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong. The create action doesnt work at all.